# python timing long program/simulation runs?

Tags: python

Using python for starting modelling/simulation runs (tuflow) and logging the runs to db
Currently on windows , python 2.7 and using timeit() .

Is it better to stick with using timeit() or to switch to using  time.clock() ?

Simulation/modelling runs can be anything from a couple of minutes to a week+.
Need reasonably accurate runtimes.

I know time.clock has been depreciated on 3.3+ but I can't see this code getting moved to 3 for a long while.

```
self.starttime = timeit.default_timer()
run sim()
self.endtime = timeit.default_timer()
self.runtime = self.starttime - self.endtime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeit`'s `timeit() function performs the code multiple times and takes the best, so it's not a great choice for lengthy runs. But your code just uses the timer, whose documentation warns that it measures elapsed time, so you will need to ensure standard running conditions in so far as you can. If you want to measure actual CPU usage, that's tricker.

When you say "reasonably accurate" times, one percent of two minutes is 2.4 seconds. The precision of `time.clock()` or the default timer is never going to be less than a second. Is that accurate enough?

To mitigate any possibility of migration to Python 3 you can define your own timing function. On Python 2 it can use `time.clock()` but at least you will only have one place to alter code if you do migrate.

Comment: Yes thats accurate enough. For a week long run, need to be accurate to within a few minutes

Comment: Plus I might not be using timeit() in the best way

Comment: I'm sorry , your code looks fine and doesn't perform repeated runs (I was thinking of the `timeit()` function). Stick with what you are doing.

Comment: My fault for not including the code when I first posted

Comment: And as you can see I have modified my answer to incorporate the updated knowledge.